# Capistrano doesn't add all files from db/migrate from git repo in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

After running `git -p` and doing y to all and then commiting the changes and pushing to Github, I run `capistrano production deploy`. Then I do `capistrano deploy:migrate`. But I get an error that says

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column doesn't exist

which clearly says that I don't have the required column in my Postgres db. Then, I checked if migrations files were there in my Ubuntu server inside `current` and every version of `releases`. There are no new migrations files that I had generated locally and pushed to Github. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: db:migrate run all migrations once against the database it's currently using. If you rollback a migration already deployed, modify it and rerun the migration in dev, you will break production. Maybe it's what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on the git side. For some reason `git add -p` wasn't adding all the files to the branch as I saw from`git status`. So I used `git add .` and it worked.